# Odoo Prefilter many2one / many2many / one2many

Tags: orm, model, odoo

How can I predefinde/prefilter a many2one field?

As example product.category has a type, in my view the user should only be able to select a product.category based on the category type.

//field in model
    category_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="product.category", string="ebay Category", required=True)

//field in view

How can I prefilter the select in view to offer only categories with type 'external'???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what `domain` is for:

To have the selectable list filtered by type 'external' add:

```
domain=[('type', '=', 'external')]
```

You can set the domain either in the field definition (python file) or in the view field (XML file). The actual filter is done by the view; if you set the domain on the field it works as an implicit default domain for the view field.

Comment: Ok, that works. What can I do when my condition is more complex and depends on the selection of another field. http://pastebin.com/Y80ARSdD

Comment: You can use a field name (without commas) on the right hand value.